# Cannot setup java 1.8 correctly for react projects after a fresh install on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: java, reactjs, react-native, ubuntu-18.04, prisma

I have recently installed java 1.8 on a fresh install of ubuntu 20.04 and seems like I may have a bad java 1.8 setup.
I'm running a docker image from a service called prisma(prisma.io), and it's broken now on this fresh install. I got some java info on the terminal plus the docker java related errors into this pastebin: pastebin.com/y0e7CbpL

I have this same setup running on a separate ubuntu 18.04, also running java 1.8 with no issues. I tried to install it exactly the same way but I guess I missed something...

Is there something obvious that can be spotted there about why java can be badly setup?
Also how likely could it be for the new ubuntu to be causing these problems, if possible at all?
Is there more info that I should provide (and how) to help figure this out?

(side note: I'm also having issues with react-native android project where it cannot build some firebase packages)
Thanks!

Comment: Hi, how did you go about installing OpenJDK? Try running the following commands to reinstall OpenJDK 1.8 on your machine: `sudo apt purge openjdk-8-jdk; sudo apt autoremove; sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk` and see if that resolves the issue. It might be an issue with the docker image itself.

Comment: It seems like a docker compose issue. You try to setup a docker container, and the java inside of that docker crashes? What should happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IT was indeed a java problem.
I could only solve this problem after copying the entire folder /usr/lib/jvm/ from another computer where this project was running fine and replace it with the one on my machine.

PS: this is the java version:

```
$java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_265"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_265-8u265-b01-0ubuntu2~18.04-b01)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.265-b01, mixed mode)
```